# FB Ads API (#17) User request limit reached

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I am working on Facebook ads api to get the account Campaign data.What I am doing here is I get list of all campaigns and doing forloop of each campaign get Campaign stat

```
$campaignSets = $account->getCampaigns(array(
      CampaignFields::ID,
      CampaignFields::NAME
));

foreach ($campaignSets as $campaign) {
      $campaign = new Campaign($campaign->id);
      $fields = array(
        InsightsFields::CAMPAIGN_NAME,
        InsightsFields::IMPRESSIONS,
        InsightsFields::UNIQUE_CLICKS,
        InsightsFields::REACH,
        InsightsFields::SPEND,
        InsightsFields::TOTAL_ACTIONS,
        InsightsFields::TOTAL_ACTION_VALUE
      );
      $params = array(
        'date_preset' => InsightsPresets::TODAY
      );
                $insights = $campaign->getInsights($fields, $params);
}
```

when executing above code I am getting error as (#17) User request limit reached.

Can anyone help me how to solve this kind of error?

Thanks,
Ronak Shah

Comment: you solve it by limiting the amount of api calls, and by waiting some time until the limit error message is gone.

Comment: yeah!! but I thought there must be anyway to get all data in a single call or else just like any way to download stat or reports in xls or csv, so I can process report and add data in DB

Comment: you can implement a delay between the calls, for example

Comment: Bad idea!! Add delay between calls

Comment: why would that be a bad idea? i´ve used this a lot of times already. check out my answer for a more specific solution.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider generating a single report against the adaccount which returns insights for all of your campaigns, this should reduce the number of requests required significantly.

```
Cursor::setDefaultUseImplicitFetch(true);

$account = new AdAccount($account_id);
$fields = array(
  InsightsFields::CAMPAIGN_NAME,
  InsightsFields::CAMPAIGN_ID,
  InsightsFields::IMPRESSIONS,
  InsightsFields::UNIQUE_CLICKS,
  InsightsFields::REACH,
  InsightsFields::SPEND,
  InsightsFields::TOTAL_ACTIONS,
  InsightsFields::TOTAL_ACTION_VALUE,
);
$params = array(
  'date_preset' => InsightsPresets::TODAY,
  'level' => 'ad',
  'limit' => 1000,
);

$insights = $account->getInsights($fields, $params);
foreach($insights as $i) {
  echo $i->campaign_id.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much, yes this is what I was looking for +1 vote but one problem here I cannot get campaign name

Comment: Campaign name is coming blank any idea about that?

Comment: updated to include the correct way to request fields. You were right all along as this changed in v2.5.

Comment: Hey Paul, Thanks for getting back to me, I just edited your answer.getInsights function accepts first argument as array of $fields

Comment: @PaulBain can you please suggest same code in python? Facing same issue but script in Python.

Comment: campaign name definitely comes back in the latest version as of today

Answer (score 1):

If you run into API limits, your only option is to reduce calls. You can do this easily by delaying API calls. I assume you are already using a Cron Job, so implement a counter that stores the last campaign you have requested the data for. When the Cron Job runs again, request the data of the next 1-x campaign data (you have to test how many are possible per Cron Job call) and store the last one again.

Also, you should batch the API calls - it will not avoid limits, but it will be a lot faster. As fast as the slowest API call in the batch.

Comment: what if I have more than 100 campaigns say I get data for first 10 campaigns and then it stopped and started throwing error.Facebook blocks call for 30 mins and my requirement is to get all campaigns data hourly and insert in DB.

Comment: ok, that´s weird. are you sure there are only 10 api calls when it comes to the api limit, or is there something else happening in the "getInsights" function? i am doing up to 50 api calls at once sometimes and it´s not a problem.

Comment: if you're using implicit fetch in the cursor e.g. `Cursor::setDefaultUseImplicitFetch(true)`, you're actually making many calls automatically during the loop, this is why we by default did not set this to be true as you would never know how many requests you're making as a developer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code and you'll never have to worry about FB's Rate Limiting/User Limit Reached.
Your script will automatically sleep as soon as you approach the limit, and then pick up from where it left after the cool down. Enjoy :)

```
import logging
import requests as rq

#Function to find the string between two strings or characters
def find_between( s, first, last ):
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""

#Function to check how close you are to the FB Rate Limit
def check_limit():
    check=rq.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/act_'+account_number+'/insights?access_token='+my_access_token)
    call=float(find_between(check.headers['x-business-use-case-usage'],'call_count":','}'))
    cpu=float(find_between(check.headers['x-business-use-case-usage'],'total_cputime":','}'))
    total=float(find_between(check.headers['x-business-use-case-usage'],'total_time":',','))
    usage=max(call,cpu,total)
    return usage

#Check if you reached 75% of the limit, if yes then back-off for 5 minutes (put this chunk in your loop, every 200-500 iterations)
if (check_limit()>75):
    print('75% Rate Limit Reached. Cooling Time 5 Minutes.')
    logging.debug('75% Rate Limit Reached. Cooling Time 5 Minutes.')
    time.sleep(300)
```