# Overcoming Rate Limiting in Facebook Marketing API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

**Specifically**, I'm trying to do something very similar to this question (with the same problem): [FB Ads API (#17) User request limit reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160992/fb-ads-api-17-user-request-limit-reached)

However, I'm trying to do this in python (and the API has changed quite a bit since '15).  Here's my code (and it kicks me out, even with the sleep time) - I'm wondering if anyone could help me in calling an array with similar info, to reduce my number of total calls.

```
my_account = AdAccount(ad_account_id)
camps = my_account.get_campaigns(fields=[Campaign.Field.name])

for campaign in camps[0:100]:
    time.sleep(5)
    print campaign[Campaign.Field.name]
    adsets = campaign.get_ad_sets([AdSet.Field.name, AdSet.Field.status])
    for adset in adsets:
        print '\t', adset[AdSet.Field.name]
        for stat in adset.get_insights(fields=[
        'impressions',
        'clicks',
        'spend',
        'unique_clicks',
        ]):
            for statfield in stat:
                print "\t\t%s:\t%s" % (statfield, stat[statfield])
```

More **generally**, how am I *meant* to code for my needs (mass alterations) within this limitation?  In reality, I want to write a code to go through and change a few options in each of my company's ad sets (e.g. "Expand Interests when..." from off to on).  We have hundreds of ad sets, and the API docs say that alterations consume 10-100 times more calls than creations (I'm getting stuck on neither, just reads!).  Is this simply a matter of, say, sleeping the code for 60 seconds between each change?  They aren't very clear on how many calls you get in a time period, or how wide the time period is for checking on those calls.  If it's a daily limitation, for example, then sleeping won't help me change 1200 ad sets' options.

I do see documentation on upgrading (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access), but when going through the review process, everything is based on a public (customer-facing, multiuser) app.  All I want to do is be able to make calls from a desktop dev-only, internal script to make bulk changes.  Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: "how would I go about getting around this limitation?" I think any answer here would probably result in that loophole being closed immediately. They're kinda a big company.... sleeping code to meet their rate limits is not "getting around" them.

Comment: Exactly.  So my wording was unfortunate.  I certainly don't mean questionable practices - I meant "getting around" in the literal sense: like sleeping.  But they aren't clear on how *much* I need to sleep, or at what point sleeping doesn't help.  Honestly, I meant things like pulling an array in one call instead of looping hundreds of calls for the same info!

Comment: @Xodarap777 were you able to get around this? How did you end up solving this ? I'm stuck in a similar situation here and I keep getting account rate limits. I almost have to edit/create 15000 Ad objects approximately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just reading the data now, why not make a batch request? I was doing the same as you but just ended up requesting more data (I had to fiddle with it since there is such a thing as too much data, FB will not allow that either) and then loop through the data.

For my purposes, I did batch async requests + sleep (10 seconds) if I hit my limit. Works well for me.

Comment: Were you trying to create/edit objects or pull them? The rate limits are different, if your just pulling data.

Comment: And were you sleeping, when you hit account rate limit or user rate limit ?

Answer (score 9):

Add this to your code and you'll never have to worry about FB's Rate Limiting.
Your script will automatically sleep as soon as you approach the limit, and then pick up from where it left after the cool down. Enjoy :)

```
import logging
import requests as rq

#Function to find the string between two strings or characters
def find_between( s, first, last ):
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""

#Function to check how close you are to the FB Rate Limit
def check_limit():
    check=rq.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/act_'+account_number+'/insights?access_token='+my_access_token)
    call=float(find_between(check.headers['x-business-use-case-usage'],'call_count":','}'))
    cpu=float(find_between(check.headers['x-business-use-case-usage'],'total_cputime":','}'))
    total=float(find_between(check.headers['x-business-use-case-usage'],'total_time":',','))
    usage=max(call,cpu,total)
    return usage

#Check if you reached 75% of the limit, if yes then back-off for 5 minutes (put this chunk in your loop, every 200-500 iterations)
if (check_limit()>75):
    print('75% Rate Limit Reached. Cooling Time 5 Minutes.')
    logging.debug('75% Rate Limit Reached. Cooling Time 5 Minutes.')
    time.sleep(300)
```

Answer (score 1):

To whom it may be useful, I've solved this problem by catching the "headers" returned after each API calls.

```
my_account = AdAccount(ad_account_id)
camps = my_account.get_campaigns(fields=[Campaign.Field.name])
for campaign in camps[0:100]:
    time.sleep(5)
    print campaign[Campaign.Field.name]
    adsets = campaign.get_ad_sets([AdSet.Field.name, AdSet.Field.status])
    for adset in adsets:
        print '\t', adset[AdSet.Field.name]
        adset_insights = adset.get_insights(fields=[
        'impressions',
        'clicks',
        'spend',
        'unique_clicks',
        ])
        for stat in adset_insights:
            for statfield in stat:
                print "\t\t%s:\t%s" % (statfield, stat[statfield])
        rate_limit = json.loads(adset_insights.headers()[
        'x-fb-ads-insights-throttle'])
        if rate_limit['acc_id_util_pct'] > your_percentage_limit:
            time.sleep(150)
```

`json.loads()` because some values are treated as text, so in order to convert it to a subscriptable object.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the mentioned solutions are that they require making a specific request to the Facebook API every second request to check the limit, which reduces the rate by half (as every second request is used to check the limit). To address this problem, I have proposed two solutions.

- The first is to monkey patch the Facebook Business SDK library and override the function responsible for making requests to the Facebook Graph API "def call(.....)". By doing this, you can check the limit in the response header of the request you have already made and then take appropriate action.
- The other solution is to use Request Throttling and then you can intercept each request send by the facebook business SDK and check the headers in each response and then taking action.

Answer (score -1):

Addition to [Smith Orlando's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68408805/10330386), there are other parameters like:

- call_count (Percentage of calls made)
- total_time (Percentage of total time)
- total_cputime (Percentage of total CPU time)

total_time and total_cputime is limited with 100.

max value of acc_id_util_pct is 100 since it is a percentage too but you can make more requests even you reached that limit because you didn't reached total_time and total_cputime limit yet.

And max call_count is calculated different for every type of request. You can learn more about this from the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting/#buc-rate-limits)

Comment: This is false. Here is my header : `x-ad-account-usage: {"acc_id_util_pct":100}` and here is the response message  `WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#17) User request limit reached"`

Comment: and the other 3 values `x-app-usage: {"call_count":0,"total_cputime":0,"total_time":0}`

Comment: This was my experiment using the api. But according to the documentation most logical reason is maybe you have only one account and I have more so I have to exceed this limit for all the accounts. The limit for each account adds up even if you are making all the requests from one account.

Comment: Ok, but this : "[...]make more requests even you reached that limit because you didn't reached total_time and total_cputime limit yet." it's not always true then