# How do I interpret Meta Marketing API Rate Limit responses?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-insights

I'm calling the Facebook marketing API on AdSets and AdInsights.  It has rate limiting and I can't figure out the what the response parameters mean so I can logically handle with sleep calls.  Three values are returned with the call:

```
x_business_use_case_usage: call_count, total_time, total_cputime
```

Here is the key:

[image: Rate limit key]

I found [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48573248/overcoming-rate-limiting-in-facebook-marketing-api), but it doesn't work.

The meta documentation says:
Total CPU Time
The amount of CPU time the request takes to process. When total_cputime reaches 100, calls may be throttled.

Total Time
The length of time the request takes to process. When total_time reaches 100, calls may be throttled.

But I am getting single digit numbers from these values and still getting throttled.